# GORM invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference when getting a value from the database

Tags: go, mysql-connector, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm making a web app with gin and gorm, I'm working in the backend right now and when I try to get the id of the last entry to create the next id with `db.Last(&post)` I get the following runtime error:

```
POST /api/new-message HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 67
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: curl/7.84.0


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:260 (0x44d475)
        panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:835 (0x44d445)
        sigpanic: panicmem()
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:853 (0x952a5d)
        (*DB).clone: dialect:           newDialect(s.dialect.GetName(), s.db),
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:204 (0x94bf30)
        (*DB).NewScope: dbClone := s.clone()
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:346 (0x94e08c)
        (*DB).Last: newScope := s.NewScope(out)
/home/th3_m0th/Golang/SVent/handlers/handlers.go:44 (0x9731cc)
        APIHandler.NewMessage: handler.db.Last(&post)
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x888c01)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/recovery.go:101 (0x888bec)
        CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x887d06)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/logger.go:240 (0x887ce9)
        LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x886dd0)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:616 (0x886a38)
        (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/home/th3_m0th/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:572 (0x88657c)
        (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2947 (0x698f2b)
        serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1991 (0x694146)
        (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 (0x467ec0)
        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
```

**Relevant code**
main.go

```
package main

import (
    "SVent/handlers"
    _ "SVent/models"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var db *gorm.DB
var apiHandler *handlers.APIHandler
var err error

func init() {
    ctx := gin.Context{}
    apiHandler = handlers.NewAPIHandler(&ctx, db)
}

func main() {
    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("DATABASE"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/", handlers.MainPage)
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("static/*.html")
    api := router.Group("/api/")
    api.POST("new-message", apiHandler.NewMessage)
    err := router.Run(":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

handlers.go

```
package handlers

import (
    "SVent/models"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/goccy/go-json"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type APIHandler struct {
    db  *gorm.DB
    ctx *gin.Context
}

func NewAPIHandler(ctx *gin.Context, db *gorm.DB) *APIHandler {
    return &APIHandler{
        db:  db,
        ctx: ctx,
    }
}

func MainPage(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", nil)
    return
}

func (handler APIHandler) NewMessage(c *gin.Context) {
    var post models.Post
    var text models.PostMsg

    msg, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"msg": http.StatusInternalServerError,
            "err": "An error ocurred. Please try again."})
        log.Fatalln(err)
        return
    }
    handler.db.Last(&post)

    err = json.Unmarshal(msg, &text)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"msg": http.StatusInternalServerError,
            "err": err.Error()})
        log.Fatalln(err)
        return
    }
    post.ID = post.ID + 1
    post.Msg = text.Msg
    post.Date = time.Now()

    handler.db.Create(post)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"msg": "Success", "err": ""})
}
```

posts.go

```
package models

import "time"

type Post struct {
    ID   int       `json:"id"`
    Msg  string    `json:"msg"`
    Date time.Time `json:"date"`
}

type PostMsg struct {
    Msg string `json:"msg"`
}
```

Also, recommendations or suggestions to improve the code are allowed, thanks!

Comment: Look up the offending line in the stactrace and fix your bug.

Comment: @Volker how? Could you please give me further information? I know where the bug is but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Look, the bug is on line 44 of /home/th3_m0th/Golang/SVent/handlers/handlers.go and I do not know which line that is. Just make sure you do not use nil interfaces or dereference nil pointers.

Comment: @Volker is in this line handler.db.Last(&post) in the handlers.go file I uploaded and I even 'initialized' the variable post like this post := models.Post{0, "", time.Now()} so I don't get why is it giving me this error. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe handler is nil or handler.db is nil.

Comment: @Volker you were right, handler.db was nil because it was 'inicializated' in the init function without a value, eliminated the init function and pasted it's code into the main function and it's working properly, thanks for helping me!